# changing number to star with data of php and with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In the design I am doing, some data (numbers: 3.2 - 4 - 4.7 - 2.7) is taken from the backend and given to me in the PHP loop `<? Php the_field ('rating');?>)`.

These numbers (3.2 - 4 - 4.7 - 2.7) must be converted to stars.

I used the following code I got from address [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/ayKZNL), but it still does not work properly.

According to the image I posted, in the design done in [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/ayKZNL), ratings in the stars-inner class are converted to width, but in the code, I wrote this does not happen.
[image].

Do you think the code I sent is problematic in terms of syntax?

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
var ratings = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ratings')].map(o => o.innerText).join('\n');
console.log(ratings);


for(const rating in ratings) {  
  for (let i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
     const starPercentage = ratings[rating] / starTotal * 100;
     console.log(starPercentage);

     const starPercentageRounded = `${(Math.round(starPercentage / 10) * 10)}%`;
     console.log(starPercentageRounded);

     const goldStar = document.querySelector(`.${rating} .stars-inner`);
     console.log(goldStar);

     goldStar.style.width = starPercentageRounded; 
     console.log(starPercentageRounded)
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

table th, 
table tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: #e7e7e7;
}
 
table th, 
table td {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
 
table th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}     

.stars-outer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.stars-outer::before {
  content: "\f006 \f006 \f006 \f006 \f006";
}

.stars-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}

.stars-inner::before {
  content: "\f005 \f005 \f005 \f005 \f005";
  color: #f8ce0b;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.attribution:hover {
  color: #1fa67a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    //wordpress code
      <td><p class="ratings"><?php the_field('rating'); ?></p></td>
      <td>
        <div class="stars-outer">
          <div class="stars-inner"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<a class="attribution" href="http://fontawesome.io/"><i class="fa fa-font-awesome"></i> fontawesome.io</a>


//html code in inspector
<div> 3.2 </div>

<div> 4 </div>

<div> 4.7 </div>

<div> 2.7 </div>
```

Comment: why are you join the rating together?  your var `ratings` it's a string you should use an array of numbers

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'ratings' you are calling is a string. You must use them as arrays.